# clearing the input value after clicking a button ($('#id').val(''); ) is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clear the input value of an input after a button is clicked. but it does not do the functionality. here is my html:

```
<input id="userNameInputId" type="text" name="PhoneNumber" >
 <button type="button" onclick="hidevalue()">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        clear
                    </button>
```

here is my js:

```
function hidevalue(){
$('#userNameInputId').val(''); 
}
```

any opinion?

Comment: Where did you put `function hidevalue()`? Do not put this function on `jQuery document ready` function.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? Did you bother to look? That should be the first place you go when you're having trouble with JS, not here.

Comment: Scoping issue..?

Comment: Oh just for the record with `onclick="hidevalue()"` you executing the function as you bind it the the click event so it only runs on page load. If you remove the `()` from the above code it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your function inside a jquery initializer for the page?

Try this if you're still having trouble.

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $('#userNameInputId').val(''); 
});
```

But I'm pretty sure you don't have it wrapped in a jquery document yet...or you haven't included jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this
document.getElementById('your elememt').innerHtml="";
Let me know if it's works for you.